# display json response from ajax call in html table

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I get the below JSON response from an AJAX call:

```
{"items":[{"name":"MP 201SPF_1C","productNo":"123","commerceItemQty":1,"price":"$350.00","leaseOrNot":"false"},{"name":"MP 201SPF_1C","productNo":"456","commerceItemQty":4,"price":"$1,400.00","leaseOrNot":"false"},{"name":"MP 201SPF_1C","productNo":"789","commerceItemQty":4,"price":"$1,400.00","leaseOrNot":"true"}]}
```

here is my code:

```
        $.getJSON(ajaxResponse, function (data) 
    { 
    var tr; 
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
    { 
    tr = $('<tr/>'); 
    tr.append("<td><h3>" + data[i].name + "</h3>""<p><strong>" + data[i].productNo + "</strong></p>""<div>" + data[i].leaseOrNot + "</div></td>"); 
    tr.append("<td>" + data[i].commerceItemQty + "</td>"); tr.append("<td>" + data[i].price + "</td>"); $('table').append(tr); 
    } 

});
```

I need to append the above JSON data to a table. How can i do it? Please help!

Comment: show you ajax call code whaty you tired?

Comment: $.getJSON(ajaxResponse,
      function (data) {
          var tr;
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
              tr = $('<tr/>');
              tr.append("<td><h3>" + data[i].name + "</h3>""<p><strong>" + data[i].productNo + "</strong></p>""<div>" + data[i].leaseOrNot + "</div></td>");
              tr.append("<td>" + data[i].commerceItemQty + "</td>");
              tr.append("<td>" + data[i].price + "</td>");
              $('table').append(tr);
          }
      });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate on items object as array is insde items object:

```
$.each(json.items,function(index,item){
console.log(item);
tr = $('<tr/>'); 
    tr.append("<td><h3>" + item.name + "</h3><p><strong>" + item.productNo + "</strong></p><div>" + item.leaseOrNot + "</div></td>"); 
    tr.append("<td>" + item.commerceItemQty + "</td>"); tr.append("<td>" +item.price + "</td>"); $('table').append(tr); 

})
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/rW2AL/)

Comment: Bad idea to mutate DOM in a loop.

Comment: it is an array of objects @YuryTarabanko

Comment: And? You can build entire html-string in memory and append it at the very end.

Answer (score 0):

```
var json={"items":[{"name":"MP201SPF_1C","productNo":"123","commerceItemQty":1,"price":"$350.00","leaseOrNot":"false"},{"name":"MP201SPF_1C","productNo":"456","commerceItemQty":4,"price":"$1,400.00","leaseOrNot":"false"},{"name":"MP201SPF_1C","productNo":"789","commerceItemQty":4,"price":"$1,400.00","leaseOrNot":"true"}]}


var table="<table><thead><tr><th>head1</th>.....</tr></thead><tbody>"
for(var i=0;i<json.items.length;i++){
   table+="<tr><td>"+json.items[i]["key name1"]+"</td>.........</tr>"
}
table+="</tbody></thead>";
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML=table;










 $.getJSON(ajaxResponse, function (data) 
    { 
    var tr; 
    for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) 
    { 
    tr = $('<tr/>'); 
    tr.append("<td><h3>" + data.items[i].name + "</h3>""<p><strong>" + data[i].productNo + "</strong></p>""<div>" + data.items[i].leaseOrNot + "</div></td>"); 
    tr.append("<td>" + data.items[i].commerceItemQty + "</td>"); tr.append("<td>" + data.items[i].price + "</td>"); $('table').append(tr); 
    } 

});
```